# How to update pages when a service worker is registered from Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm registering a service worker from `create react app` and I'm getting good scored in lighthouse for being a progressive web app and I can install the web app from the Chrome address bar, all is good

**BUT** when I update the content on the website nobody gets to see it unless they clear their cache, which they don't. How can I ensure they see the latest content while still getting a top score on lighthouse for being a progressive web app?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Router } from './router';
import './scss/index.scss';

ReactDOM.render(<Router />, document.getElementById('shell'));
serviceWorker.register();
```

Comment: Define "update the content on the website".

Comment: This has to do more with CDN caching

Comment: If I change an image or bit of text or CSS it doesn't get shown to users who have visited the site before unless they clear their cache first.

Comment: You'd need to see what you're actually sending the client (caching etc), define your server architecture (e.g., as Horatiu is suggesting) etc.

Comment: The service worker is generated from `create react app`, so this is known and I'm pushing to GitHub Pages so this is also known.

Comment: Using `Service Workers` its by their design they serve local cached copy first on subsequent visit. Once you update any content, that content gets updated in service worker so on the next visit to the same page or any other page, your new content will be served from service worker. Thus you should be very careful in making sure what you serve via service worker in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To service worker update your cache, you'll need to close ALL TABs of your website.
Another way is use this package to do this job.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loopmode/cra-workbox-refresh

It will do all the job for you, and after install the new files, it shows up a button allowing you to update the page